# Custom Listview does not display ImageView properly

Tags: android, listview

I created a custom ListView with a custum layout defined in a xml file.
My XML looks like this: http://pastebin.com/1TA715MG
and my ListAdapter like this: http://pastebin.com/kqTWAJE5

If i create a list and fill it with Products, there should be displayed a thumb at the left side of each item. This works for 98% of the items, but sometimes there is just a transparent image. If i now scroll down and up fast, so that the item is not longer displayed, the image appears Ô.o this effect is really strange in my opinion, is there something that may cause the bug?

Comment: In the adapter create a breakpoint on condition `item.thumb == null`. I suspect that for some elements its `null` for example. Also, does the missing image occur only for a few products or randomly for any product in the list?

Comment: it occurs for random products... and the strange thing is that the image is displayed if I scroll the view out of the display and in one time...

Comment: I think the item still has no thumb. The reason why you see a thumb when you scroll up and down is that you use the provided convertView object in the `getView` method. Since a listView recycles the views it  is the case that the ImageView is initialized with the thumb of another item object. Please feel free to ask again if you don't understand what I mean.

Comment: this woult mean that the items imageview uses the same drawable/picture as another item, am I right?

Comment: Right your view is reused and could still contain text and images from an item that was displayed former in this view. So if you don't explicitly override the imageView with an empty image there could be such a strange behaviour.
By the way, nice to see that you use the convertView and don't inflate the view everytime getView is called.

Comment: but that wont fix my problem, and also does not explain it, because it just doesnt display the image, BUT display the correct product name , description

Comment: @user1951516 Jsut debug the thing. First check if the condition `if (list_product_thumbnail != null && item.thumb != null) {` is false at any time. This would mean that the thumbnail is not set sometimes. If you don't see the thumbnail image but the condition is always met, you have clearly a problem with the `Drawable`.

Comment: Yes, I second that andr. I bet that the drawable is null for these items.

Comment: I did so, and the result was that the thumb was null. But i still dont understand why scrolling the view out of the display and in again solves the problem...